# Making Linq Queries run Parallel

Tags: c#, linq

I have maybe 40 linq queries and I would like to execute them paralleled. 
There's no dependencies between the queries so running each in parallel should be okay.  I was wondering how do I make the below code "Faster"/"Better".

Two of my basic Queries and the union:

```
public override void Filter()
{
    var general = (from z in ctx.Interactions
                   where z.ActivityDate <= EndDate && z.ActivityDate >= StartDate &&
                         z.Indepth == false && z.Type == InteractionTypes.General
                   select new { Entries = z.EntryCount }).Sum(x => x.Entries).GetValueOrDefault();

    var Indepth = (from z in ctx.Interactions
                   join program in ctx.Programs on z.Program.Id equals program.Id
                   where z.ActivityDate <= EndDate && z.ActivityDate >= StartDate && z.Indepth == true && program.Reportable
                   select z).Count();

    ...Remaining 38 queries....  

    AddQuarterlyInfo("# of General Inquiries", "1.1", general);                 
    AddQuarterlyInfo("# of In-Depth Counselling and Information Services Interviews", "1.2", Indepth);
    ...Union remaining 38 queries...
}
```

Comment: MSDN, plinq is optimized for helping you...
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @ShahzadQureshi That parallelizes the work of items within each query, it doesn't parallelize separate queries.

Comment: I assumed you were using EF because of the ctx. If it's sharepoint there's also a `ExecuteQueryAsync` there.

Comment: In parallel, asynchronously, or both?

Comment: I assume `ctx` is a DbContext or DataContext. Nobody seems to be aware that these objects aren't thread safe. This should *not* be done in parallel. The question is how to improve the code. Then I wonder why we the other queries aren't shown, because I bet that many of them can be combined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me, although I can't speak for performance without having your same data source.

```
    int general = 0;
    int indepth = 0;
    List<Task> queryTasks = new List<Task>
        {
            new Task(() =>
            {
                general = (from a in ctx.Interactions
                    select new {}).Count();
            }),
            new Task(() =>
            {
                indepth = (from a in ctx.Interactions
                    select new {}).Count();
            })
        };
    Parallel.ForEach(queryTasks, q => q.RunSynchronously());

    await Task.WhenAll(queryTasks);

    AddQuarterlyInfo("# of General Inquiries", "1.1", general);                 
    AddQuarterlyInfo("# of In-Depth Counselling and Information Services Interviews", "1.2", indepth);
```

Comment: So `Parallel.ForEach` or `Task.WaitAll`? You need to use either not both.

Comment: No, if I removed the Parallel.ForEach then the Task.WaitAll would wait forever the way this is written, because the tasks would never start.

Comment: To combine many tasks into one use `await Task.WhenAll()`. To wait them synchronously thus block current thread use `Task.WaitAll()`.

Comment: Don't use `ctx` in mutliple threads anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can use async queries if you use entity framework 6 by doing something like this:

```
var blogs = (from b in db.Blogs 
             orderby b.Name 
             select b).ToListAsync(); 

var blogs2 = (from b in db.Blogs 
             orderby b.Name 
             select b).ToListAsync(); 

var result = await Task.WhenAll(new [] {blogs, blogs2}));

//this is reached when all queries are completed.
```

Comment: Don't use `Wait()`. Use `await Task.WhenAll()` instead.

Comment: @abatishchev aight :)

Comment: Don't use `db` in mutliple threads anyway.